# How to configure Docker to use a FTP Client in Java?

Tags: java, docker, ftp

I am trying to run a simple Java FTP Client (org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient) program with Docker containerization to obtain some file from a remote FTP server.

Running the app locally (without docker) works fine. The containerized app however does not return any data. Example program:

```
ftpClient.connect(host, port);
ftpClient.login(usr, pwd);
System.out.println(ftpClient.getReplyString());
filenameList = ftpClient.listNames();
System.out.println(ftpClient.getReplyString());
```

With Docker, I get the following error message: Connection closed without indication.

Interesting however is that I also receive: 
230 User logged in. Any hints?

Comment: Is the other FTP server in the same network as your computer? If yes, the FTP library uses ftp port commands, and those don't work properly is docker

Comment: No its not, it is in an external Network.

Comment: Make sure to use ftp passive mode. This will make the ftp server tell your ftp client the connection details for the (next) data connection.

Comment: @user3460948: Thank you very much, it worked; adding the line `ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();` made the difference!